# resize cubiccurve on jframe resisize

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-2d, paintcomponent

I have this curve shape, and I wanted the width and height resize accordingly relative to the size of my JFrame, for example my JFrame size is setSize(440, 300); -- and then if I maximize my JFrame I wanted the curve shape to get resized as well, so that the shape would maintain its actual figure. Any help, appreciate in advance. Thanks,

here is my code:

```
float offset = (float) Math.sin(Math.PI);

x1 = offset;
y1 = (height/4.0f) - 4.0f;

x1ctl = ((width/4) - 140) + 90.0f;
y1ctl = ((height/4) - 100) + 20.0f;

x2ctl = ((width/4) - 10.0f) + 60.0f;
y2ctl = ((height/4) - 8.0f) + 1.0f;

x2 = (width/2.0f) - 20.0f;
y2 = offset - 4.0f;

curve = new CubicCurve2D.Float(
        x1,y1,
        x1ctl,y1ctl,
        x2ctl,y2ctl,
        x2,y2);

g2d.draw(curve);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override `paintComponent` and use component's dimensions. Here is an example based on the arguments in the question:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CubicCurveComponentTest extends JComponent {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        float offset = (float) Math.sin(Math.PI);

        float x1 = offset;
        float y1 = (getHeight()/4.0f) - 4.0f;

        float x1ctl = ((getWidth()/4) - 140) + 90.0f;
        float y1ctl = ((getHeight()/4) - 100) + 20.0f;

        float x2ctl = ((getWidth()/4) - 10.0f) + 60.0f;
        float y2ctl = ((getHeight()/4) - 8.0f) + 1.0f;

        float x2 = (getWidth()/2.0f) - 20.0f;
        float y2 = offset - 4.0f;

        CubicCurve2D curve = new CubicCurve2D.Float(
                x1,y1,
                x1ctl,y1ctl,
                x2ctl,y2ctl,
                x2,y2);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.draw(curve);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {    
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Cubic Curve Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(440, 300);
        f.add(new CubicCurveComponentTest());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Runnable doCreateAndShowGUI = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doCreateAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

***EDIT: coordinates example***

Here is an example of coordinates derived from given initial dimensions of the container (440, 300) and the magic numbers used in original calculation:

```
    float x1 = 0;
    float y1 = getHeight() * 0.24f;

    float x1ctl =  getWidth() * 0.125f;
    float y1ctl = 0;

    float x2ctl = getWidth() * 0.24f;
    float y2ctl = getHeight() * 0.22f;

    float x2 = getWidth() * 0.45f;
    float y2 = -getHeight() * 0.013f;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I appreciate it. Yes it is overriding paintComponent and I already done this though. What I was looking for is that as you resize your JFrame, is there a way the curve could maintain its actual appearance? for example, here the frame size is set to (440, 300) and if you try to Maximize the JFrame the cubicurve starts to appear to be something like a straight line loosing its natural curve form. I trying to find a way so that the curve points will go along as the frame is being resize?

Comment: @eLL Not sure what is the logic behind the curve coordinates in your example, but it seems they are tied to 440 and 300. There should be a more generic formula so the curve keeps its form when the container is resized.

Comment: it is exactly what you think. I'm looking for a formula for these curve points, so that whether the Jframe is resize bigger or smaller the cubiccurve keeps it form: do you know a more precise way how to achieve that?

float x1ctl = ((getWidth()/4) - 140) + 90.0f;
float y1ctl = ((getHeight()/4) - 100) + 20.0f;
float x2ctl = ((getWidth()/4) - 10.0f) + 60.0f;
float y2ctl = ((getHeight()/4) - 8.0f) + 1.0f;

Any help, appreciate in advance.

Comment: @eLL Not sure how you derived the numbers for coordinates. See if my last edit helps you. I recalculated the coefficients based on the numbers you specified.

Comment: Thanks a lot Max. Those coordinates are far more better, as it does not damage the form of the curve whenever i re-size the frame. thumbs up!